# django integrate htmls into templates

Tags: html, django, templates, include

i have a django 'templating' question

if i have in views.py:

```
def cv(request):
 if request.user.is_authenticated():
     cv = OpenCv.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)
 return render_to_response('cv/cv.html', {
    'object_list': cv,

    }, 
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and in cv.html something like:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
<li>
First Name {{ object.first_name }} <br />
Last Name {{ object.last_name }} <br /> 
Url {{object.url}} <br />
Picture {{object.picture}} <br />
Bio {{object.bio}} <br />
Date of birth {{object.date_birth}} <br />

{% endfor %}
```

but i want this content to appear on the profile.html page too, how can i do it?
a smple `{% include "cv/cv.html" %}` in the profile.html doesn't work.
Also, is there another way to 'parse the object list' than explicitly write all the objects, like above?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Have You also sent object_list in profile method in views.py?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: {% include "cv/cv.html" %} ??

Comment: i've sent object_list in views.py of cv application,(see above) should i have sent it somewhere else also?

yes, the path is correct, i've just edited now

Comment: Yes, see Ignacio's answer, you need to pass object_list in the context when rendering profile.html in the profile view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `object_list` to `profile.html` as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you're asking, but I suspect a [custom template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) might be what you're after.